# Running the latest elasticsearch cluster in kubernetes

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, configuration, cluster-computing

I have managed to run the latest elasticsearch in Kubernetes with only ONE pod. I would like to extend this to a full-blown elasticsearch cluster on Kubernetes. I have checked out https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster but it is not maintained anymore and does not have the latest ES docker image. I tried to use the .yaml files from that github with the latest ES image from docker hub but have not been able to set up the cluster. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: This question is a little open ended. What exactly is the problem you're having when you try to run multiple ES nodes? I run ES 6 on a k8s cluster, but I need to know exactly how to answer your question. Are you having trouble with the ES config or with k8s setup?

Comment: ES config. I can only see 1 node in _cluster/health

Comment: please add your ES config and k8s config to the question

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55216342/elasticsearch-highly-available-setup-in-kubernetes). I've answered that question and it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I have got it up and running with 6.6.0, swap-off and/or memory-lock, 3 master nodes and 2 data nodes.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Kudos.

Comment: I am not sure as I did it on my own. Your reply was late.